# Pass AMP state in action xhr

Tags: amp-html

i am working on amp-form. in action-xhr i have to pass a amp state with url.

leadProfileId is amp state.

```
<form method="post" action-xhr='@currentHostUrl/api/stocks/leadProfileId/negotiate' id="submitOfferForm" target="_top"
                  on="submit-success: AMP.setState({ selectedOffer : null })">
                <input hidden name="priceOffered" [value]="selectedOffer">
                <input hidden name="mobileNumber" [value]="mobileNo">
            </form>
```

i have tried following approaches but it's not working.

1. '@currentHostUrl/api/stocks/{{leadProfileId}}/negotiate'
2. "'@currentHostUrl/api/stocks/'leadProfileId'/negotiate'"

Comment: where is the `amp-state`? you have an action but no state.

Comment: leadProfileId is amp state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Jay Gray** correctly asked you about where you have the **amp-state** tag? It is unclear where you write data using `AMP.setState({ anyData: 'anyValue'})`

---

Unfortunately, I don't know how to make the action-xhr attribute bind from amp-state. See this topic: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/11222

When we don't know how to bind something in AMP, the **amp-list** component usually helps us out. Solution:

```html
<!--
     This is the minimum valid AMP HTML document. Type away
     here and the AMP Validator will re-check your document on the fly.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ⚡>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="canonical" href="self.html" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1" />
  <style amp-boilerplate>
    body {
      -webkit-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      -moz-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      -ms-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
    
    @-moz-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
    
    @-ms-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
    
    @-o-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <noscript>
    <style amp-boilerplate>
      body {
        -webkit-animation: none;
        -moz-animation: none;
        -ms-animation: none;
        animation: none;
      }
    </style>
  </noscript>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <amp-state id="localState">
    <script type="application/json">
      {
        "leadProfileId": "api"
      }
    </script>
  </amp-state>

  <h2>AMP-Form</h2>

  <amp-list width="auto" height="100" items="." src="amp-state:localState" single-item>
    <template type="amp-mustache">

      <form method="post" target="_top" action-xhr="https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/{{leadProfileId}}/verify-form-input-text-xhr/">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <div submit-success>Form send successful!</div>
        <div submit-error>Form send failed!</div>
      </form>

    </template>
  </amp-list>

</body>

</html>
```

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/alexandr-kazakov/pen/LYNWYzY?editors=1000